# How can I change the color of :before on hover of another element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
span{
  color: #666;
}
span:before{
 content: "\f059";
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 15px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
 color: #999;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

span:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span>something</span>
```

Now I need to make that icon red too on hover of `<span>`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following selector:

```
span:hover,
span:hover:before {
  color: red;
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
span {
  color: #666;
}
span:before{
  content: "\f059";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  color: #999;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

span:hover,
span:hover:before {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span>something</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want just the before elem to change color :

```css
span{
  color: #666;
}
span:before{
 content: "\f059";
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 15px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
 color: #999;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

span:hover:before{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span>something</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add little css and you are done

```
span:hover:before {
  color: red;
}
```

Here is the snippet

```css
span{
  color: #666;
}
span:before{
 content: "\f059";
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 15px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
 color: #999;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

span:hover{
  color: red;
}

span:hover:before {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span>something</span>
```

Comment: Thank you .. upvote

Comment: Welcome :) @MartinAJ